# Calculateting video RAM requirements?

Tags: memory, video

I am reading the book [Structured Computer Organization](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132916525) by Andrew Tanenbaum. I am going through the section of video memories and I have the following example:

> A video RAM with 1920 × 1080 pixels at 3 bytes/pixel requires over 6.2 MB

However, from what I know to calculate how much space it requires I would use:

- 1920x1080 = 2073600 pixels
- 2073600x24 = 49766400 bits
- 49766400/8/1024/1024 = 5.9 MB

So Why does it say I would need over 6.2 MB. Please point out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Side note: Why are you converting to bits (2073600*(3*8)), and then converting back to bytes later on (49766400/8)?

Comment: Yes, my mistake to calculate the result two times.

Comment: Well, it was technically correct, but I almost didn't notice the `/8`. I had already started my answer with "You're both wrong...." ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, and the book is right (but also wrong). If you split up your calculation differently, you'll see the book's mistake right away:

> 2073600pixels * (3 bytes/pixel) = 6,220,800 bytes

Now, the mistake is obvious. The book is using 1,000^2 = MB as a conversion factor instead of 1024^2 = MB. This is easy to do, since 1000^2 **is** the appropriate conversion when you're talking about *disk size*.

However, 1024^2 has always been used as a MB for anything to do with RAM or the CPU, because those pieces of hardware are naturally inclined to work with powers of 2. Historically, these two conversion factors have both been called the megabyte. If you follow the metric system, then etymologically speaking, megabyte should refer to 1000^2 bytes. Thus, the new name for 1024^2 bytes is the [Mebibite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte), and is abbreviated as MiB — which both less gratifying, and less confusing.

Now, let's take the equation full circle:

> 2073600pixels * (3 bytes/pixel) = 6,220,800 bytes = 6.2 * 1000^2 MB ~ 5.93 * 1024^2 MiB

Comment: Thank you I spend a good amount of time wondering. At many points we are expected to work with 1024 when converting from Bytes to MB. Is there a way to know which one to use?

Comment: It's basically by convention. Anything to do with RAM or the CPU will use 1024, because it's 2^10. CDs, Hard drives, SSDs, and flash drives will use 1000.

Comment: However, when going further I get the following example: 
"Let us make a simple calculation. Consider a 1024 × 768 color video with 3 bytes/pixel."
If I use the same way to calculate I would have 2.4MB per frame. The book states the result is 2.25MB which contradicts the previous example.

Comment: Is there a list of errata for this book? It's possible that someone has noticed (and reported) the issue to the author or publisher.